# Why does my JavaScript Prime Number-Generator not work?

Tags: javascript, math, web-applications, primes

The aim of this program is to list all the prime numbers from 1 up.
I am a complete novice. I began writing this in C++ (unsuccessfully) and translated to this (JS)
I am aware of some problems but don't know how to solve them:
handling global variables,
writing replaces,
no timeout before writing, etc.
is it important that i use an external JS file?
In summary, how do i make this work?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

var number = 3; //to be run through the prime test
var prime = [2]; //numbers found to be prime
var found = 1; //counter for primes found
var runs = 0; //counter for times number has been tested
//numbers are tested against all smaller found primes
function test()
{
    window.scroll(0,document.height); //automatically view the latest prime
    var line = document.createElement("div");
    while(runs < found && (prime[runs] < (number / 2))) //has number passed all tests
    {
        if(number % prime[runs] !== 0) //is number divisible by smaller prime
        {
            runs = runs + 1; //number passed a test
        }
        else //number is not prime
        {
            number = number + 1; //next number generated
            runs = 0; //reset test counter for next number
            setTimeout(test, 100); //start running next number tests
        }
    } //number passed all tests
line.innerHTML = number; //prime number displayed
document.body.appendChild(line);
prime[found] = number; //prime number saved for testing
found = found + 1; //counter for found is increased
number = number + 1; //next number generated
runs = 0; //reset test counter for next number
setTimeout(test, 100); //start running next number tests
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="test()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not incrementing found

Comment: Learn the correct syntax/use of a `for` loop - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: for should be while. (change made)

Comment: Is that an infinite loop? you are calling test in test

Comment: Yes, it is an infinite loop. Is that forbidden?

Comment: found is now being incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the mathematical side,

```
var prime = [1];
```

`1` isn't a prime, and since `1` divides every number,

```
while (runs < found) //has number passed all tests
{
    if (number % prime[runs] !== 0) //is number divisible by smaller prime
    {
        runs = runs + 1; //number passed a test
    }
    else //number failed a test
    {
        number = number + 1; //next number generated
        runs = 0; //reset test counter for next number
        setTimeout(test, 1000); //start running next number tests
    }
} //number passed all tests
```

always enters the `else` branch for `runs = 0`.

You can start with `var prime = [2];` or with `var prime = [];` and `var found = 0;`.

Comment: great! wow! it's working! any way of having it auto-scroll to the bottom?

Comment: problem found: it's not filtering multiples of 5.

Comment: One thing I overlooked: `var number = 1;` <- you should start with a number larger than the prime you have, set it to 3 at the start. Don't see yet why it should skip multiples of 5.

Comment: @user2363023 Starting with `var number = 3;` I see no such problem. But I can't get it to stop, inserting a condition `number < 100` for example is completely ignored. What's going on??

Comment: What's the idea behind `if(number % prime[Math.round(runs / 2)] !== 0)`?

Comment: a number being tested for being prime is sequentially divided by all the prime numbers between 1 and half its value.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

1. `for (runs < found)`

   You appear to want a [`while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) here. `for` loops cannot consist just of a condition.
2. `document.writeln()` cannot be used after the `document` has finished loading and has *closed*. Using them after this will re-open the `document`, resetting it to blank.

   To modify the DOM after this, you'll need to use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) or [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) and [`element.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild).

   ```
   var line = document.createElement('div');
   line.innerHTML = number;
   document.body.appendChild(line);
   ```
3. To avoid infinite recursion and give the UI thread a chance to update the display of the page, you can [use a timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) when calling `test` again:

   ```
   setTimeout(test, 100);
   ```

Comment: would step 2 produce a list?

Comment: @user2363023 It can if you create a new element each time. Move the `var line = ...` inside `test()` rather than having it as a global.